# Group Array by target index Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Am trying to create a groups from the array by target index

**for example this my Array**

Am trying to target `index [1]` of each child of the data array

```
data = [('0', 'COL1', 'date'),('1', 'COL2', 'date'), ('2', 'COL1', 'date'), ('3', 'COL3', 'date') , ('4', 'COL1', 'date'),('6', 'COL2', 'date')]
```

**expected output is**

```
[[('0', 'COL1', 'date'),('2', 'COL1', 'date'),('4', 'COL1', 'date')],[('1', 'COL2', 'date'),('6', 'COL2', 'date')],[('3', 'COL3', 'date')]]
```

Thank you any help will appreciated!

Comment: [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)?

Comment: @JonClements can you give close example.

Comment: Trying to find you a duplicate that explains it but it comes up a lot of times: you basically sort it by the key and materialise the grouped items as a list, then group it by the key, eg: `[list(g) for k, g in groupby(sorted(data, key=lambda L: L[1]), lambda L: L[1])] `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array(data)
data[data[:,1].argsort()]
```

Comment: am having issue printing out 

data[data[:,1].argsort()]

but its ok, this line is enough
np.array(data)

Comment: What is the issue you are facing with printing?

Comment: That will give numpy array, incase you like you can convert to list:   
 data[data[:,1].argsort()].tolist()